# Using result of formula in another calculation

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, int, openpyxl

I would like to use the value calculated in the second, "for i in range" statement to calculate a new value using the fourth, "for i in range" statement; however, I receive the error: "could not convert string to float: 'E2*37.5'"

How do I call upon the numerical value calculated in, `sheet['F{}',format(i)] ='E{}*37.5'.format(i)` instead of the formula/string?

```
import openpyxl


wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('camdatatest.xlsx', read_only= False, data_only = True)

# Assuming you are working with Sheet1
sheet = wb['Sheet1']

for i in range(2,80):
    sheet['D{}'.format(i)] = '=C{}/3'.format(i)
for i in range(2,80):
    sheet['F{}'.format(i)] = '=E{}*37.5'.format(i)
for i in range(2,80):
    sheet['H{}'.format(i)] = '=D{}*G2*50'.format(i) 
for i in range(2,80):
    sheet['I{}'.format(i)].value = float(sheet['F{}'.format(i)].value)/float(sheet['H{}'.format(i)].value)



wb.save('camdatatestoutput.xlsx' , data_only= True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately that's not quite possible [because](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/usage.html)

> openpyxl never evaluates formula

There are other libraries that may do so. However your problem can be overcome by recognizing that you can use yet another cell reference instead of the calculated value here.

```
for i in range(2,80):
    sheet['I{}'.format(i)] = '=E{}*37.5/H{}'.format(i,i)
```

Note that you can't set the value for the Ix cell because you don't actually have a value for the Ex or Hx cells. (well you might have but it's not clear from your question if you do)

Comment: Thanks @e4c5, works perfectly!! I'm slowly getting the hang

Comment: glad to have been of help. All the best with your project.